# What are some ways to find the second order quantum phase transition (PT) critical point?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-optics

The standard way appears to be finding the steady state (ss) solutions of the order parameter of the system of interest.  Since the ground state properties of the system changes before and after crossing phase transition critical point, the point where the ss solution changes, taken to be the critical point of the system.  I am wondering, is there any other way to find PT critical point other than finding ss solutions.

Comment: It might be helpful to sharpen the question. Are you asking specfically about quantum phase transitions, or does your questions apply to classical phase transitions as well? Or how to distinguish quantum from classical critical points? Are you asking an empirical questions (how to identify phase transitions experimentally), or a theoretical question?

Comment: @Thomas I am specifically asking about quantum phase transitions.  I am asking a theoretical question.  For example, take Dicke system/2D Ising model, the most common way to find the PT critical point is to evaluate the steady state solutions of order parameters of the system.  The order parameter is zero in one phase and non-zero in another indicates phase transition, the point where the value changes from zero to non-zero is taken to be PT critical point.  I am asking whether there exist any other way to find the PT other than finding steady state solutions of order parameter.